# Prove the upper limit of a bounded complex-valued sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let {$x_n$} be a bounded complex-valued sequence.
> (i) Prove that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|x_n|}\leq 1$. 
> (ii) Prove that if $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|x_n|}<1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$.

My attempt on (i) is like this: 
{$\sqrt[n]{|x_n|}$} is a bounded (non-negative) real-valued sequence. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and consider a sequence {$|x_n|+\epsilon$}. Then, since $|x_n|+\epsilon>0$ for each $n$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|x_n|+\epsilon}=1$ by theorem 3.20 (in Baby Rudin). Since $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n\leq \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}t_n$ if $s_n\leq t_n$ for $n\leq N$ where $N$ is fixed, the desired inequality follows.

I'm not sure if the above proof is valid or not.
For part (ii), I haven't come up with a good approach for a long time. I have no idea how to use the assumption. At this point, I feel like Theorem 3.20 (e) in Baby Rudin, that is,

> If $|x|<1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x^n=0$

seems to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using Theorem 3.20 correctly. The theorem says $\lim p^{1/n}=$ if $p >0$ but you cannot make $p$ dependent on $n$.

Let $|x_n|\leq M$ for all $n$ where $0<M<\infty$ Then $|x_n|^{1/n} \leq M^{1/n} \to 1$ from which we get (i).

(ii) Let $m=\lim\sup |x_n|^{1/n} $. Then $m<1$.  Let $m <m'<1$. Now $\lim\sup |x_n|^{1/n} <m'$ which implies there exists $q$ such that $|x_k|^{1/k}<m'$ for all $k>q$. But then $|x_k|<m'^{k}$ for $k >q$ and $m'^{k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ becasue $m'<1$. This proves (ii).

Comment: Ah, so introducing that $M$ is exactly where I need "boundedness" of the sequence, right? Thank you!

Comment: @friendOfMath Yes, that is right.